# Passing objects to tableview controller does not work but view controller works

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, core-data

I am new to iOS development and core data fetchresultscontroller. I have a problem passing/segue an object from a tableview to another tableview.

Here is my code below:

```
   if([[segue identifier]isEqualToString:@"expenses"]){
        ExpensesTableViewController *exp = (ExpensesTableViewController*)[segue destinationViewController];
        NSIndexPath *path = [[self tableView]indexPathForSelectedRow];
        Budget *b = [_fetch objectAtIndexPath:path];
        [exp setCurrentBudget:b];
    }
```

when tap one of the tableview cells, I am expecting an object sent to another segue tableview. However I get this error message:

```
"Unknown class ExpenseInBudgetTableViewController in Interface Builder file."...
"[UITableViewController setCurrentBudget:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8d74a60"...
"Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UITableViewController setCurrentBudget:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8d74a60'"
```

I have correctly inserted the matching class in the custom class field and.. not sure what else i should check.

Also for some reason, if I pass an object to a normal ViewController, with the same code (but ViewContoller class), the expected outcome is correct.

So, I was wondering if there is a big difference passing objects to a tableview controller and the normal view controller or what am i doing wrong?

Many thanks.

Comment: Have you noticed that in your code you have ExpensesTableViewController while in the error message you have ExpenseInBudgetTableViewController. Is there a clue here?

Comment: yes I was actually looking for why it is saying 'Unknown class ExpenseInBudgetTableViewController in Interface Builder file'. I checked that the current tableview has an import of the second tableview and in the second tableview it has a property of currentBudget

Comment: #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "Budget.h"
(at)interface ExpensesTableViewController : UITableViewController
(at)property (nonatomic, strong)Budget *currentBudget;
(at)end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you've made a mistake in your storyboard, did you remember to set the Class Name of the view controller you're segueing to.

Comment: You are correct, I previously deleted a class name that the name is similar and it was still hanging around in the custom class drop down box, I didn't read it thoroughly. Thanks very much